# Object comparison in numba jitclass

Tags: python-3.x, jit, numba

How can I compare two numba jitclass objects to see if they are the same?

I have the following code

```
from numba import jitclass
import numba

node_type = numba.deferred_type()
DoubleLinkedNode_spec = [
  ('value', numba.optional(numba.typeof(1.0))),
  ('prev', numba.optional(node_type)),
  ('next', numba.optional(node_type))
]

@jitclass(DoubleLinkedNode_spec)
class DoubleLinkedNode(object):
  def __init__(self, value, prev, next):
    self.value = value
    self.prev = prev
    self.next = next

node_type.define(DoubleLinkedNode.class_type.instance_type)

n1 = DoubleLinkedNode(1.0, None, None)
n2 = DoubleLinkedNode(2.0, n1, None)
n1.next = n2
print(f'{n2}\n{n2.prev.next}')
#outputs: 
#  <numba.jitclass.boxing.DoubleLinkedNode object at 0x7fbf26923850>
#  <numba.jitclass.boxing.DoubleLinkedNode object at 0x7fbf256b3cf0>
print(f'Next is None. n1: {n1.next is None}   n2: {n2.next is None}')
#outputs: 
#  Next is None. n1: False   n2: True
```

This is a standard node for a double linked list.

The `is` operator does not work, since they are not in the same address of memory.

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I compare two objects then?
3. `is None` seems to work. But can i trust it?

Comment: Could you specify, how do want to compare the two objects? Is comparing the similarity of `value` attributes enough or does one have to compare `next` and `prev` as well?

Comment: I want to compare `next` and `prev`. If I assert `a = b` I expect `a == b` to evaluate to `True`

Comment: Have a look at the ```__eq__(self, other)``` method [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)

Comment: When running your code I get the following warning ```@jitclass(DoubleLinkedNode_spec)
NumbaDeprecationWarning: The 'numba.jitclass' decorator has moved to 'numba.experimental.jitclass' to better reflect the experimental nature of the functionality. Please update your imports to accommodate this change and see http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#change-of-jitclass-location for the time frame.``` It would also appear that jitclass does not support class members so defining ```__eq__``` is not an option as it creates ```__hash__```, which errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dunder methods don't work properly with jitclasses so I implemented something similar to `__eq__`.

```py
from numba.experimental import jitclass
import numba

node_type = numba.deferred_type()
DoubleLinkedNode_spec = [
    ('value', numba.optional(numba.typeof(1.0))),
    ('prev', numba.optional(node_type)),
    ('next', numba.optional(node_type))
]

@jitclass(DoubleLinkedNode_spec)
class DoubleLinkedNode(object):
    def __init__(self, value, prev, next):
        self.value = value
        self.prev = prev
        self.next = next

    def equal(self, other):
        return self.prevs_eq(other) and self.nexts_eq(other)

    def prevs_eq(self, other):
        while True:
            if self.prev is None:
                return self.value == other.value
            if not self.value == other.value:
                return False

            self = self.prev
            other = other.prev

    def nexts_eq(self, other):
        while True:
            if self.next is None:
                return self.value == other.value
            if not self.value == other.value:
                return False

            self = self.next
            other = other.next

node_type.define(DoubleLinkedNode.class_type.instance_type)

n1 = DoubleLinkedNode(1.0, None, None)
n2 = DoubleLinkedNode(2.0, n1, None)
n1.next = n2

print(f'{n2.equal(n2.prev.next)}')
# True
```

You have to call the `equal` method which is inelegant, but if you rename it to `__eq__` it won't work at all. This works for what I have tested so far.